# setTimeout and updating correct tab in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, timer, tabs

Am writing the code for a simple Chrome extension, but am having problems with clearing the correct instance of the `setTimeout` and updating the correct Chrome tab. I want to set timer for request to a URL and if response is received, the corresponding instance should be cleared. if response times out, timer function should update the corresponding window with `dialog.html`. The problem is, a response clears the last timer and the timer function updates the current tab. I tried, `window.setTimeout` and passing `request.tabId` as parameter to timer function, but both did not work. Thanks for your help,

background.js

```
var flag = false;
var new_url;
var timeout;

function resp_timeout(){
  var dialog_url = chrome.extension.getURL("dialog.html"); 
  chrome.tabs.update({url: dialog_url});
}


chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function interceptRequest(request) {
    if (isOn) {     
       original_url = request.url;                      
       if (request && request.url) {        
        if(flag){
        new_url = request.url; 
        }
       else { 
        new_url = request.url.replace("http","https");
        timeout = setTimeout(resp_timeout, 500);  
       }
        return { redirectUrl: new_url }
      }   
   }   
}, {urls: ['http://*/*']}, ['blocking']); 

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details) {
  if (isOn) {    
    clearTimeout(timeout);    
    return {responseHeaders:headers};
  }
}, {urls: ['*://*/*']}, ['responseHeaders','blocking']);
```

dialog.js:

```
var bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();

function ok_handler(){  
 window.open(bg.original_url, "_self");
}

function cancel_handler(){
  window.close();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.querySelector('#ok_button').addEventListener('click', ok_handler);
  document.querySelector('#cancel_button').addEventListener('click', cancel_handler);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to store multiple timeouts, one per active request. You can identify them by `requestId`. Also, you'll need to generate different callback functions, each one to update the proper tab:

```
var timeouts = {};

function get_resp_timeout(tabId, requestId) {
   return function() {
      var dialog_url = chrome.extension.getURL("dialog.html"); 
      chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {url: dialog_url});
      delete timeouts[requestId];
   }
}
...
        timeouts[request.requestId] = setTimeout(
           get_resp_timeout(request.tabId, request.requestId), 500);
...
    clearTimeout(timeouts[details.requestId]);
    delete timeouts[details.requestId];
```